# Can't center item at lower screen size CSS

Tags: html, css

I made a button selector that looks great on my normal screen size, but when trying to make it responsive down to smaller screen sizes I noticed that it no longer looks right. My guess is that since there are less pixels, the rounding that the browser is doing is causing it to look not centered.

Here is the design at a larger screen size:
[image]

And here it is at a smaller screen size:

[image]

You can see that the inner part of the circles are no longer centered and even differ randomly (the top right one is shifted more to the top left while the middle and bottom left are shifted to the bottom right).

Here is the css

```
.selectorButton {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: v-bind(primaryColor);
    width: clamp(14px, 1.1vw, 30px);
    aspect-ratio: 1/ 1;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    position: relative;
    /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
}

.selectorButton::before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: inherit;
    background-color: #121a20;
    width: clamp(12px, 0.9vw, 25px);
    aspect-ratio: 1 /1;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.6s;
    background: #11181e;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #070a0c,
        inset -5px -5px 10px #1b2630;
}
```

Note, I did try multiple ways of centering the pseudo element, like flex box and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` with `position: absolute` and `left: 50%; top: 50%` but neither worked.

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this to make it always look centered?

Comment: Use SVG instead

Comment: Use borders instead of pseudo elements :)

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue when asking this kind of question.

Comment: @JiaSH oh yea. I Guess I can do the same thing with just borders lol. That worked great and made things a lot simpler, thanks.